# could not convert string to float: 'K5'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to call on a file that has strings in it so I can count how many of that one type of string there is but when I get an error that a string cannot be converted to a float. The file is very large but a small section would look like {K5, M2 K5, M0, M0, M2}. I want to then count how many of each matching entry there are.

```
file = 'IMF.txt'
spec_type = np.loadtxt(file, skiprows = 1, usecols = 1)
```

Comment: Replace the text file with the text itself or provide an example of what is inside it.
Also, provide your error type

Comment: Your title says something different than your question text. Please make sure to copy the exact error text into your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) by default expects numeric data. You can specify `dtype='S2'` for strings of length 2:

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

file = StringIO("""
0 K5
1 M2
3 K5
5 M0
6 M0
7 M2""")

# replace file with 'IMF.txt'
spec_type = np.loadtxt(file, skiprows=1, usecols=1, dtype='S2')
```

Returns:

```
print(spec_type)

array([b'K5', b'M2', b'K5', b'M0', b'M0', b'M2'], dtype='|S2')
```